# Apache Redirect Loop

Tags: apache, loops, url-rewriting, infinite

I am getting a "webpage has a redirect loop" error on my rewrite rules in Apache.

I want to have clean URLs for GET requests so if a user types www.flavor.com/vanilla that the server runs www.flavor.com/?s=vanilla but the url reads just www.flavor.com/vanilla so I added this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /?s=$1
```

This works fine, but I also want to have www.flavor.com/?s=vanilla to redirect to www.flavor.com/vanilla so I added this which is causing a loop.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([a-z]+)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

I tried adding [END] and [L] to the both, but no help.  I've rewritten this 200 times and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499088) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930010/3410935) this should help: `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200`.

Full file:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /?s=$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried this, but am getting the following error message: Not Found

The requested URL /example was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at mysite.org Port 80