# Redirect loop using Apache mod_rewrite (clean URLs)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My situation is very similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/499068/595306) (in fact, the code is very similar). I've been trying to create a `.htaccess` file to use URLs without file extensions so that e.g. `https://example.com/file` finds `file.html` in the appropriate directory, but also that `https://example.com/file.html` redirects (using a HTTP redirect) to `https://example.com/file` so there is only one canonical URL. With the following `.htaccess`:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect <...>.php, <...>.html to <...> (without file extension)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

I've been running into a redirect loop just as in the question mentioned above. (In my case, finding the corresponding file is achieved by `MultiViews` instead of a separate `RewriteRule`.)

However, with [a solution adopted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10031576):

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect <...>.php, <...>.html to <...> (without file extension)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.+)\.(php|html)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R]
```

there is no redirect loop. I’d be interested to find out where the difference comes from. Aren’t both files functionally equivalent? How come that using a “normal” `RewriteRule` creates a loop, while using `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn’t?

Note that I’m **not** looking for a way to get clean URLs (I could just use the second version of my file or the answer to the question linked above, which looks at `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}`), but for the **reason** why these two approaches work/don’t work, so this is not the same question as the one linked above.

**Note:** I'm seeing the same problem using only mod_rewrite (without `MultiViews`), so it doesn't seem to be due to the order of execution of `MultiViews` and mod_rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

## Redirect <...>.php, <...>.html to <...> (without file extension)
# This works...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.+)\.(php|html)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R]
# But this doesn’t!
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [L,R]

# Find file with file extension .php or .html on the filesystem for a URL
# without file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Where’s the difference? I would expect both approaches to work because the internal rewrite to a file is at the very end of the `.htaccess` with an `[L]` flag, so there shouldn't be any processing or redirecting happening afterwards, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`RewriteRule` directive's documentation](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewriterule), you'll notice the following:

> On the first `RewriteRule`, it is matched against the (%-decoded)
>   URL-path of the request, or, in per-directory context (see below), the
>   URL path relative to that per-directory context. Subsequent patterns
>   are matched against the output of the last matching `RewriteRule`.

Since, it will be matched on a per directory basis, once you put the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

the `REQUEST_URI` variable changes, and mod-rewrite parses the URI again. This leads to `MultiViews` rewriting the URL to the proper file matching this redirected URL and causing a loop (URI changes on every rewrite).

Now, when you put `THE_REQUEST` variable to match against, the URI may change on internal rewrites, but the **actual request as received by the server** would never change unless a redirect is performed.

Comment: Same question here as for the other answer: Shouldn't the `[L]` flag stop the mod_rewrite loop (in my last example)? Why does it still keep going after e.g. `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]`? Even if other rules would still match, shouldn't it stop at `[L]`?

Comment: @Socob The [`L` flag documentation](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/flags#flag_l) has: "_It is therefore important, if you are using `RewriteRule` directives in one of these contexts, that you take explicit steps to avoid rules looping, and **not count solely on the `[L]` flag to terminate execution of a series of rules**, as shown below._".

Comment: Yes, I know that part of the documentation. What I’m trying to understand is _why_ `[L]` doesn’t help me in this case. Is it because of the following part?

“It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the `.htaccess` file or `<Directory>` section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.”

Comment: @Socob ah, yes. I removed the wrong paragraph when I pasted text in previous comment.

Comment: @Socob Once `L` flag is encountered, mod-rewrite does whatever is asked of it. Now, if you have an internal redirect applied, the `REQUEST_URI` gets updated, and the .htaccess is processed from the start again. If you do not have `L` flag, mod-rewrite will continue to match rules until end of file and then start from the beginning once more, if there were successful `REQUEST_URI` changes..

Answer (score 1):

```
# But this doesn’t!
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Reason why this commented rule doesn't work and causes rewrite loop because your other rule is adding `.html` extension and changing `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable to `/file.html` thus causing this rule to execute again. And taking out `.html` from rule causes other rule to fire again. This goes on until max recursion limit is reached.

You also need to understand that `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop until a rule doesn't match. Since both rules keep firing therefore `mod_rewrite` keeps looping.

Reason why rule based on `THE_REQUEST` works because `THE_REQUEST` variable doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite rules.

Comment: But shouldn't the `[L]` flag stop the mod_rewrite loop? Why does it still keep going after e.g. `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]`?

Comment: No `L` flag doesn't stop the loop. `L` flag merely ends the current rule and forces `mod_rewrite` to run the loop again.

Comment: By “current rule”, do you mean “current pass of the `.htaccess` file”? Otherwise the flag would be kind of useless...

Comment: Yes that is current. It ends the current `RewriteRule` of where it is used and then acts as `continue` for the mod_rewrite loop. Also note that if you use `END` instead (available with Apache 2.4+) then that will definitely terminate the `mod_rewrite` loop.

Comment: [Also see the flow chart in this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)