# Apache: How can I both redirect foo.html to foo and rewrite foo to foo.html?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

I'm hosting a website that's just a bunch of static .html files. I don't want to have the `.html` file extension in the URLs, so I've added a rewrite rule:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

This is simple enough and works fine, but I would now *also* like to redirect (302) URLs ending in `.html` to the canonical path, i.e. without the file extension. I've tried the following:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html$
  RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

However, that leads to an endless redirect loop. I suspect that's because the second rule, the internal rewrite, is still triggering the first rule, the external redirect.

How else can I achieve this? I've looked through all the rewrite flags and tried a bunch that sounded promising, but I haven't managed to make this work. How can I both rewrite from `foo.html` to `foo` and still do an internal rewrite from `foo` to `foo.html`?

Answer (score 2):

There are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33862716/1190388) asking about how this procedure works. Use `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.html
RewriteRule \.html$ /%1 [R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Ouch, makes me doubt my Google-Fu :( Works brilliant.

Comment: This is very useful. How would one extend it so that the following works too? /foo => /foo/, /foo.html => /foo/ and /foo/ is as is and all three return foo.html. Thank you.